# Tables' schema for MySQL driven multi-language website

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I'm working on multi-lang website. Trying to design optimal db schema for this purpose.

[image]

As you see, there are 2 tables: `langs` and `menu`. **My idea is following:**

For ex. lets take a look at multi-language navigation generation from MySQL table. In PHP backend, while generating navigation from database

- Get all data from `menu` table's row
- Left join second table - `langs` (by `name` field of `menu` table )
  and get data from defined language's column (for ex. en, ru)

How do you think, is it optimal way, or is there more efficient solution? Please, give me database related answers, not file. (for ex. gettext,... etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if the `langs` table contained a `language` column, with one row for each translation. This allows you to add another language later and only have to apply data changes (rather than having to re-write queries).

As you've already implied, performing a left join and falling back to a default language held directly in the `menus` table is also a good idea (in which case, you don't need to hold a translation for e.g. `en` in the `langs` table, since the english version will always be available).

You may also want to consider storing country-specific translations (if, say, there are multiple spanish speaking countries where the translations can be different), and following a fallback strategy of finding: `language-country`, `language`, `English` translations.

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu - yes, although I'd make the primary key of the `langs` table `ID, language` so that all of the translations for menu `1` have an `ID` of `1`.

Comment: Should I use foreign key, like the second solution? Will iw work faster?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu - foreign keys *aren't*, primarily, a mechanism for improving access speed. Their primary purpose is to ensure *referential integrity* -

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize further like so:

- tokenname: id, token (eg, (1, program), (2, menu))
- localizations: id,
  tokenname_id, lang, text

Tables that reference strings then refer to the string by tokenname.id as a foreign key.

Note that you will need some kind of mini templating language for text localizations.

Comment: "Tables that reference strings then refer to the string by tokenname.id as a foreign key." I don't understand well this part. Please, either explain here or I'm waiting you in chatroom. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6113/multilang-website